# Ember-Data. Add Child record for many2many & one2many

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9gA4y/1/

**I have following model:**

```
contact => (many2many) => tags
contact => (one2many) => address
```

**Ember Data Model:**

```
App.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),  
  tags: hasMany('App.Tag'),
  addresses: hasMany('App.Address')
});

App.Address = DS.Model.extend({
  street: attr('string'),
  country: attr('string'),
  contacts: belongsTo('App.Contact')
})
App.Tag = DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  contacts: hasMany('App.Contact')
});
```

**I figured out adding New contact record**

- How do I associate existing, Address to Newly created contact. (one 2 Many)
- How do I associate existing, Tags to Newly created contact. (Many 2 Many)
- How do I delete associations in a existing contact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hasMany` relationships can be manipulated through `addObject`, `addObjects` or `removeObject`.

```
contact.get('addresses').pushObject(address);
contact.get('addresses').removeObject(address);
```

You could also set contact on the address

```
address.set('contact', contact);
address.set('contact', null);
```

Also, you note that you should use the singular form for a belongsTo association (`contact` not `contacts`):

```
App.Address = DS.Model.extend({
  street: attr('string'),
  country: attr('string'),
  contact: belongsTo('App.Contact')
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var contact = App.Contact.find(1),
    address = App.Address.find(1),
    tag = App.Tag.find(1);

contact.get('addresses').addObject(address);
contact.get('tags').addObject(tag);

this.get('store').commit(); //saves address and tag to contact

contact.get('tags').removeObject(tag);

this.get('store').commit(); //removes tag from contact
```